# Coded UI Test - Code worked in TestMethod, but doesn't work in TestInitialize method and TestCleanUp method

Tags: c#

For example:

```
XamlWindow.Launch(Constants.appIdentifier);
```

worked well in `TestMethod`, but doesn't work in `TestInitialize` method.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException was unhandled by user code. Message=Exception occurred while trying to launch the app. Verify that the app is installed: Object reference not set to an instance of an object., AutomationId of Tile:'{...}'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was because I didn't call `Playback.Initialize()`.

Comment: Can you explain?  How do I "initialize the playback"?

Comment: I found it: Playback.Initialize().  Please put this in the Answer and then I can remove my downvote.